# How to get the tag without a href link

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, tags

in wordrpess i am using wp_list_tag to generate the tags but i need the tags without the link can any one help me to get the tag without the a href link

thanks,
Ram

Comment: Ram, we don't normally do "sig" lines on SO. Feel free to put your website on your profile page, though.

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `get_terms()` method to get an array and generate your HTML?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms (look at the examples section)

```
$terms = get_terms("tags");
$count = count($terms);
if($count > 0){
     echo "<ul>";
     foreach ($terms as $term) {
       echo "<li>".$term->name."</li>";

     }
     echo "</ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
$terms = get_terms( 'cars', array('fields'    => 'names'))
```

the result is an array of names ;)

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add below code:

```
<?php
    $tags = get_tags();
    $html = '<div class="post_tags">';
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        $html .= "{$tag->name}";
    }
    $html .= '</div>';
    echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: @ram you check this?

Answer (score -1):

You could use jQuery to remove it, I'm sure there are other alternative's but if you're looking for an *easy way out*, try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.foo').removeAttr('href');
});
```

**example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ExxRX/